# How to set a UIView to be of certain size?

Tags: uiview, interface-builder

Suppose i need to place a `UIView` of size `320 x 376` onto my Window?

How can i control this from the Interface Builder?

**ANSWERED:** Image below shows how to do it visually

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the size Inspector (In Xcode 4, it's Command-Option-5; the icon is a ruler). From there you can type in a size.